# awk: calling a function outside of awk

Tags: bash, shell, awk

## Update:

I'm working on a modular shell script which calls `usage()` in different level of subprocess. The script `sample.sh` has the structure resembles below:

```
sample.sh
├─ ...
├─ usage()
├─ awk
    ├─ usage()
├─ ...
```

`usage()` displays brief information on how to use the script (e.g. available arguments and its descriptions). When executed for the first time, `usage()` is displayed in the beginning of the script. Examples of other conditions for `usage()` invocation include:

1. `awk` fails to validate input from `stdio` or files
2. argument`--help` is received
3. other user-derived failures are occurred

I'd like to call identical function, `usage()`, from shell and its direct child process, `awk`.

---

## Original Question:

Function, `usage()` of `sample.sh` prints its print statement as desired.

```
$cat sample.sh
#!/bin/sh
awk '
    BEGIN {
        usage()
    }
    function usage() {
        print "function inside of awk"
    }
'
$./sample.sh
function inside of awk
```

To take out `usage()` from `awk` and put it as a local function in `sample.sh~`, I tried:

```
$cat sample.sh~
#!/bin/sh
usage() {
    print "function outside of awk"
}    
awk '
    BEGIN {
        usage()
    }
'
$./sample.sh~
awk: calling undefined function usage
 source line number 3
```

As we observe, we get the error message saying "undefined function usage" in `sample.sh~`. How should I improve it?

Comment: awk is not shell just like C is not shell. You should no more expect to be able to call a shell function outside of awk than you can call a shell function outside of C. If you tell us what you want to DO (not HOW you want to do it) with some sample input and expected output we can help you.

Answer (score 4):

I find a way to call  function out of awk

put below code in a file, such as call it a.sh

```
$ cat a.sh
usage() {
  print "function outside of awk"
 }

$ chmod +x a.sh
```

then you can call the function in awk

```
#!/bin/sh
awk '
    BEGIN {
       system(". a.sh;usage")
    }'
```

Answer (score 2):

A child process cannot *call* a function in the parent, and vice versa. Not even in the same language.

What you can do, is start another instance of the shell script that contains your awk script. For example, save this in a script called `./script.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh -e

usage() {
    echo usage: ...
    exit 1
}

test "$1" = --usage && usage

awk -v usage_script="$0" '
function usage() { system(usage_script " --usage") }
BEGIN {
    usage()
}'
```

Make it executable, and run as `./script.sh`. In this script, the `usage` function inside the inner `awk` script simply re-runs the containing shell script with the `--usage` script. Keep in mind that there will be 3 processes here: shell -> awk -> shell. It's not possible to do this in a single process.

**Original answer**

If you move the `usage` function definition outside of `awk`, then it's normal that you cannot execute from inside. If you want to execute `awk` commands you have to be inside of an `awk` interpreter, and can only use what is defined inside.

Note sure if this is what you're looking for, but you can move the function definition to another `awk` file and have `awk` process it, for example:

```
cat <<EOF > functions.awk
function usage() {
    print "function in functions.awk"
}
EOF
awk -f functions.awk -e '
    BEGIN {
        usage()
    }
'
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. Please see my updated question. Your answer is good only if `usage()` displays information specifically for the scope of `awk`. My intention is to display general usage information about the shell. If I put the `usage()` in `awk`, I'll have to invoke `awk` just to call `usage()` outside of `awk`.

Answer (score 2):

With `bash`, another option is to *export* shell functions with `export -f`, which then become available to `awk` via the `system()` call:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

usage() {
  echo "function outside of awk"
}

# Export the usage() function.
export -f usage

awk '
  BEGIN { 
    system("/usr/bin/env bash -c usage") 
  }'
```

Note that `awk` invokes `sh` with `system()`, which may or may not be `bash` - if it IS `bash` (e.g., on OSX), you don't strictly need the `/usr/bin/env bash -c` portion, but leaving it in should make it work on most platforms (that have bash).